# Размер картинки, зависящий от размера родителя

Tags: вёрстка, css

Делаю адаптивную вестку и столкнулся с проблемой.
В некоторых постах есть картинки. Надо сделать так, чтоб при изменении родительского элемента менялись размеры и самой картинки. Вот такая задача. Желательно это сделать без JavaScript и кросбраузерно (кроме IE6).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Хороший вопрос. Здесь нужно использовать процентные величины. Например родитель #main, потомок обычная картинка img.

Тогда можем поработать с css:

```
#main { width: 100%; height: 150px; }
#main img { width: 40%; height: 100%; }
```

img возьмёт величины своего родителя, и относительно их будет вычислять свои размеры. Вообще, в таких ситуациях не желательно использовать js, а процентные величины. У меня может быть отключен js.